# Get NEventStore head revision

Tags: c#, neventstore

I've got a new ES stream that's already got half a million events in it (no snapshots yet... I know, I'm getting there) and a simple client that atm is only appending (even more) events.

`NEventStore.OpenStream(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue)` takes a very long time to open the stream initially; after which I store the last revision and from then on only `NEventStore.OpenStream(lastRevision, int.MaxValue)` to append again. The problem's only on initial start.

Is there a mechanism within `NEventStore` to either simply append without opening, or to determine the head revision without opening the whole stream so I can then open from the last version and append. Of course I could also go direct to the database and query, but that's taking on a dependency I feel I shouldn't need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already mentioned a possible solution: Snapshots.

This example opens a stream from the latest snapshot and adds a new snapshot after events are commited.

```
// Get the latest snapshot
var latestSnapshot = _eventStore.Advanced.GetSnapshot(streamId, int.MaxValue);            

// Open the stream from the snapshot if there is one, otherwise open the stream as normal
using (var stream = latestSnapshot == null ? 
    _eventStore.OpenStream(streamId) : 
    _eventStore.OpenStream(latestSnapshot, int.MaxValue))
{
    // Add events and commit
    stream.Add(new EventMessage());
    stream.CommitChanges(Guid.NewGuid());

    // Add a new snapshot (with no payload)
    _eventStore.Advanced.AddSnapshot(
        new Snapshot(streamId, stream.StreamRevision, string.Empty));
}
```

It is probably not necessary to add new snapshots this often. It's just an example to show how snapshots work.

Comment: Thanks, I knew creating a snapshot at the end of the stream would allow me to load from the snapshot forward, but is the GetSnapshot more efficient getting the latest snapshot if there are lots of them? I hoped there might be an easy way to get the latest revision from the stream direct.

Comment: Ok looking at the GetSnapshot definition as it's retrieving the last snapshot prior to [int.MaxValue] I'm expecting it is optimised so I've added code in-process to add a snapshot every 10000 revisions. Will revert and accept if this works out and nothing more direct is offered...

Comment: I understand it's not the perfect solution for your scenario, but I don't think there is a better way. AFAIK there is also no way of removing old snapshots.

Comment: You could also create more than one stream. What about creating a new stream for each commit? Sounds too crazy?

Comment: Heh, way too crazy. In the short term I just needed to start capturing this primary event, ultimately I will have an aggregate sourced from the stream and will be creating real snapshots by which time the problem will disappear. That said, the string.Empty (null wouldn't work) snapshot every 10000 has given me a fair solution, so I'll accept as an answer. Thx.

Comment: Ok, great! I updated the answer to use string.Empty instead of null.